# Problemas al recorrer arreglo con ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

Hola tengo el siguiente arreglo que me envían desde un servidor

```
[
{
    IdProfesor:"154",
    Nombre: " Juan Pérez",
    Foto: "foto.png",
    Preferencias: {
        Especialidad: "Física",
        Correo: "email@email.com"
    },
    Clases: [
        {Edificio: "Central", Hora: "12:00", Curso: "Física 1", Cupos: 12},
        {Edificio: "Facultad de Ingenieria", Hora: "14:00", Curso: "Física 2", Cupos: 10},
        {Edificio: "Laboratorio", Hora: "16:00", Curso: "Laboratorio Física moderna", Cupos: 15}
    ]
},
{
    IdProfesor:"189",
    Nombre: "María Poblete",
    Foto: "foto.png",
    Preferencias: {
        Especialidad: "Cálculo",
        Correo: "email@email.com"
    },
    Clases: [
        {Edificio: "Central", Hora: "12:00", Curso: "Cálculo 3", Cupos: 45},
        {Edificio: "Facultad de Ingenieria", Hora: "14:00", Curso: "Cálculo 2", Cupos: 32},
        {Edificio: "Central", Hora: "16:00", Curso: "Cálculo Aplicado", Cupos: 20}
    ]
}
]
```

Estuve buscando pero no encuentro como recorrer el arreglo con ngFor y me arroja el siguiente error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

claramente me dice que no puede iterar 2 arreglos, entonces son las Clases las que tendría que transformar a objetos

alguien me podría ayudar con esto

de antemano gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir el código donde intentas utilizar ngFor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con los datos que tienes perfectamente puedes trabajar.

```
<pre>

  <span  *ngFor="let dato of datos">
    {{dato.Nombre}}<br>
    <b>Clases</b>
    <span *ngFor="let clase of dato.Clases ">
     - {{clase.Edificio}}
    </span>
    
    <hr>

    {{dato | json}}

    </span>
  
</pre>
```

Solo tienes que repetir la estructura para los `*ngFor` anidados.

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exfmrg).